# Is it possible to avoid linking gsl and openmp everytime?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, g++, openmp

I'm working on my own shared library which heavily depends on [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) and OpenMP

The final user should be able to import my library into c++ code

`#include "mylib/mylib.h"`

and ideally compile it with something simple as this

`g++ myprog.cpp -lmylib`

Now, as it currently stands I have to link GSL and OpenMP libraries every time

`g++ myprog.cpp -lgsl -fopenmp -lmylib`

otherwise I got the following error for gsl and no threading with OpenMP

```
g++ -o myprog myprog.cpp -lmlip
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccu7Mpg1.o: undefined reference to symbol 'gsl_vector_subvector'
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.so.25: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'myprog' failed
make: *** [myprog] Error 1
```

Below is the cmake file I'm using

```
find_package(GSL)
find_package(OpenMP)
add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ${GSL_LIBRARIES} OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
target_compile_options(mylib PUBLIC -O3 -Wall)
install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
install(DIRECTORY . DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/mylib FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

Is it possible at all for mylib to link to gsl somehow? Please note I'm fairly new to the concept of creating and linking libraries.

**Update on GSL**

I did some research and crafted the following snippet which solves the  problem for linking GSL.

```
add_library (GSL_LIB STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(GSL_LIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GSL_ROOT_DIR}/lib/libgsl.a)
```

However this approach does not seem to work for OpenMP. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgomp.a(team.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against hidden symbol `gomp_tls_data' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgomp.a(oacc-init.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against hidden symbol `goacc_tls_data' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: If `gsl` stuff is not exposed as part of public interface then you should be able to easily merge / statically link it into your library.

Comment: @user7860670 Can you expand on this one. Do you mean just changing PUBLIC to PRIVATE? As I mentioned this is all new to me...